# Ö (O with double dots) in Mysql record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a row in a MySQL table with "ö". The whole word is "företag".

How do I select that word in a sql query?

I've tried with företag but it didn't work. The table is using utf8.

Comment: try the "LIKE" statement

Comment: For the record, the double dots as a symbol over a vowel are called "umlauts" (a single pair of dots is an "umlaut").

Comment: The table is using utf-8, ok, but what about the field itself? It's using the table default charset? What about the connection? If you try to retrieve an "ö" from your db through an ASCII connection you won't get it because of the limitations of ASCII connection.

Comment: Which utf-8 encoding are you using? They handle umlauts differently.

Comment: This question will probably not be answered with so little information provided. Please post the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable and information on what client you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'f_retag';
```

('_' is the single character wildcard for LIKE statements)

If you are using a terminal, make sure the terminal is using UTF-8. Try:

```
 echo $LANG
```

Also try forcing the character set when starting the mysql command:

```
 mysql --default-character-set=utf-8
```

Otherwise, please give more details about what language and environment you are using to access the DB.

Comment: But if I have a records set like foretag & företag, using the above query will return me both. If the user is only interested in ö then?

Comment: The SELECT ... LIKE was only for if the problem was on the command line. If that isn't helpful, expand the question and tell us a bit more about your setup, like what language, drivers, etc. you are using...

Comment: This is not the answer, querying on diacritics (not using wildcards) is no problem in mysql, just mind the relevant settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try running following query before running your select:

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Just tested it on my local MySQL (the table was created with UTF8 charset):

```
mysql> select * from xxx where s='företag';
+----------+
| s        |
+----------+
| företag |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @tbl table(name varchar(50))
insert into @tbl select 'företag' union all select 'foretag'

SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE name = 'företag';

SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE name like '%ö%';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to write an accented character in Unicode.  For example, "Ä" can also be written as "A\u0308".  The relevant Unicode document is ["Unicode Normalization Forms"](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/), but it is not easy reading.